# Expression Engine (2.6.x) Email Form - Email missing certain fields

Tags: email, forms

Creating a form for our a client and its refusing to send certain fields to the recipient. Consistently, (as of now) this includes: Name, Company and Email. Everything else sends.

Also, how does one have form validation in EE? I put name="required[]" and it didn't affect or change anything. Granted, I didn't have an initial name="required" without the "[]". So that perhaps screwed that up.

So what exactly is the problem here? Below is the code followed by the email:

```
  <div id="contactForm" class="appnitro">
  {exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="fakeemail@gmail.com" charset="utf-8"}
           <div class="form_description"></div>                  
     <ul >
  <li id="li_1" >
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
  <span>
     <input id="element_1_1" name="name" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="25" value=""/>
  </span>
  <span>
  </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Please provide your name.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_2" >
  <label class="description" for="element_2">Company </label>
  <div>
     <input id="element_2" name="message" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>Please provide your company.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_3" >
  <label class="description" for="element_3">Title </label>
  <div>
     <input id="element_3" name="message[]" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>Please provide your title. </small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_5" >
  <label class="description" for="element_5">Email </label>
  <div>
     <input id="element_5" name="from" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_5"><small>Please provide your email.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_4" >
  <label class="description" for="element_4">Phone </label>
  <span>
     <input id="element_4_1" name="message[]" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
     <br>
     <label for="element_4_1">(###)</label>
  </span>
  <span>
     <input id="element_4_2" name="message[]" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
     <br>
     <label for="element_4_2">###</label>
  </span>
  <span>
     <input id="element_4_3" name="message[]" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
     <br>
     <label for="element_4_3">####</label>
  </span>
  <p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>Please enter in your phone number with area code.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_6" >
  <label class="description" for="element_6">Contact Preference </label>
  <span>
     <input id="element_6_1" name="message[]" class="element radio" type="radio" value="Email" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_6_1">Email</label>
     <input id="element_6_2" name="message[]" class="element radio" type="radio" value="Phone" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_6_2">Phone</label>

  </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_6"><small>Please select your preference to be reached.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_7" >
  <label class="description" for="element_7">Your Industry </label>
  <div>
  <select class="element select medium" id="element_7" name="message[]"> 
     <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="Advertising and Marketing" >Advertising and Marketing</option>
     <option value="Airline" >Airline</option>
     <option value="Automotive" >Automotive</option>
     <option value="Catalog" >Catalog</option>
     <option value="Communications" >Communications</option>
     <option value="Consumer Package Goods" >Consumer Package Goods</option>
     <option value="Education" >Education</option>
     <option value="Energy" >Energy</option>
     <option value="Entertainment and Gaming" >Entertainment and Gaming</option>
     <option value="Financial Services" >Financial Services</option>
     <option value="Government" >Government</option>
     <option value="Healthcare/Pharma" >Healthcare/Pharma</option>
     <option value="Hospitality" >Hospitality</option>
     <option value="Insurance" >Insurance</option>
     <option value="Media" >Media</option>
     <option value="Non-Profit" >Non-Profit</option>
     <option value="Publishing" >Publishing</option>
     <option value="Real Estate" >Real Estate</option>
     <option value="Restaurants" >Restaurants</option>
     <option value="Retail and Catalog" >Retail and Catalog</option>
     <option value="Technology" >Technology</option>
     <option value="Telecommunications" >Telecommunications</option>
     <option value="Travel" >Travel</option>
     <option value="Utilities" >Utilities</option>
     <option value="Other" >Other</option>
  </select>
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_7"><small>Please select your industry.</small></p> 
  </li>    <li id="li_8" >
  <label class="description" for="element_8">What Solutions are you interested in? (Please select all that apply.) </label>
  <span>
     <input id="element_8_1" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Marketing Database Solutions" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_1">Marketing Database Solutions</label>
     <input id="element_8_2" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Integrated Database and Email Marketing Solutions" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_2">Integrated Database and Email Marketing Solutions</label>
     <input id="element_8_3" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Real-Time Interactive Marketing" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_3">Real-Time Interactive Marketing</label>
     <input id="element_8_4" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Mobile Marketing" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_4">Mobile Marketing</label>
     <input id="element_8_5" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Analytics and Modeling" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_5">Analytics and Modeling</label>
     <input id="element_8_6" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Strategic MArketing Insight" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_6">Strategic MArketing Insight</label>
     <input id="element_8_7" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Business Intelligence" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_7">Business Intelligence</label>
     <input id="element_8_8" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Data- Decision Points National Consumer Database" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_8">Data- Decision Points National Consumer Database</label>
     <input id="element_8_9" name="message[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Campaign Execution" />
     <label class="choice" for="element_8_9">Campaign Execution</label>
  </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_8"><small>Select all solutions which interest you.</small></p> 
  </li>
  <li id="li_9" ><textarea name="message[]" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea><p class="guidelines" id="guide_9"><small>Please enter your message here.</small></p></li>
  <li class="buttons">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="720615" />
         <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </li>
     </ul>
  {/exp:email:contact_form}
  </div>
```

Email:

```
Lord Admiral
302
423
2342
Email
Automotive
Real-Time Interactive Marketing
Mobile Marketing
dasdasd
```

So, name and company are missing from the above and then so is email. I have no idea why and I'm on a time limit here because this was thrown at me at the last second due to fantastic internal management.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Switched to **Devdemon Forms**, though now I'm not getting any emails at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you switched forms I'll still post an answer as it may help someone else.

The "required" parameter is a bit misleading, it doesn't actually validate the field, to quote the docs "This field allows you to have required information that is included at top of each email. Useful for support emails where the information can be readonly or hidden."

If you want item headings in the received email you can do this with a hidden field:

```
<label for="my_name_field">Name </label>
<input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--Name--">
<input id="my_name_field" name="message[]" value=""/>
```

Then in the email message you'd get:

```
--Name--
Fred Bloggs
```